# Adding table to LINQ to SQL data context

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to add a table from my database to my LINQ to SQL data context. It wont let me. Looking at the table in the designer in visual studio it seems it isn't recognising the Id as a primary key. I cant see anything wrong with the table. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is my table;

```
USE [fldt_bt_wbc]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO        
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO        
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO        

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[btRequests](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [RequestType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ConversationID] [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_btRequests] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[btRequests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_btRequests_RequestType] FOREIGN KEY([RequestType])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RequestType] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[btRequests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_btRequests_RequestType]
GO
```

Comment: There isnt a message. When i try to drag the table into the designer cursor turns into a circle with a cross.

Comment: A read only designer file? Stabbing in the dark, really

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour in a new, clean project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pleun, I created a clean fresh project and it worked.